# Vetor de struct em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, struct

Não consigo achar o erro nesse codigo meu de um exercicio. Ele imprime certo a primeira leitura, depois imprime coisas aleatorias. Não consegui descobrir se o erro está na leitura ou na impressão.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*Defina uma estrutura que irá representar bandas de música.
Essa estrutura deve ter o nome da banda, que tipo de música ela toca,
 o número de integrantes e em que posição do ranking essa banda está dentre as suas 5 bandas favoritas.*/
#define TAM 2

 typedef struct
 {
     char nome[20],tipo[15];
     int integrantes,posicao;
 }BANDAS[TAM];

int main()
{

    BANDAS banda[TAM];
    ler (&banda);

    mostrar(banda);


    return 0;
}

void ler (BANDAS *banda)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        printf ("Diga qual o nome da banda: ");
        gets(banda[i]->nome);
    __fpurge(stdin);

        printf ("Tipo de musica: ");
        gets (banda[i]->tipo);
    __fpurge (stdin);

        printf ("Quantos integrantes tem a banda: ");
        scanf ("%d",&banda[i]->integrantes);
     __fpurge (stdin);
        printf ("Posicao no seu top 5: ");
        scanf ("%d",&banda[i]->posicao);
        __fpurge (stdin);
    }
}

void mostrar (BANDAS banda)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<TAM;i++){

    printf ("Nome: %s\n",banda[i].nome);
    printf ("Tipo de musica: %s\n",banda[i].tipo);
    printf ("Numero de integrantes: %d \n",banda[i].integrantes);
    printf ("Posicao no seu TOP 5: %d \n",banda[i].posicao);
    }

}
```

Estou iterando errado na leitura? Como seria o certo ?

Comment: Poderia postar qual é a saída que você está obtendo?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que, o maior problema do programa, seja a declaração:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[20],tipo[15];
    int integrantes,posicao;
} BANDAS[TAM];
```

Nesta declaração, você está criando um **tipo** *array*, com `TAM` posições.

E na função *main()*, quando você declara:

```
BANDAS banda[TAM];
```

Na verdade, está criando uma **matriz**, já que o *typedef* já define um *array*.

A tradução desta instrução pelo compilador ficaria algo do tipo (exemplo):

```
struct BANDAS banda[2][2];
```

e provavelmente, não é isso que você quer que o programa faça.

---

Se você realmente pretende criar o **tipo** `BANDAS` como *array*, a solução é alterar a declaração da variável `banda` no main para:

```
BANDAS banda;
```

e na função `ler()`,  alterar as referências ao *array* para, por exemplo:

```
...
printf("Diga qual o nome da banda: ");
gets((*banda)[i].nome);
...
```

Segue abaixo, uma versão funcional do programa com estas alterações:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 2

typedef struct
{
    char nome[20];
    char tipo[15];
    int integrantes,posicao;
} BANDAS[TAM];

void ler (BANDAS *banda);
void mostrar (BANDAS banda);

int main()
{
    BANDAS banda;

    ler (&banda);
    mostrar(banda);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void ler (BANDAS *banda)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("Diga qual o nome da banda: ");
        gets((*banda)[i].nome);
        printf("Tipo de musica: ");
        gets ((*banda)[i].tipo);
        printf("Quantos integrantes tem a banda: ");
        scanf("%d",&(*banda)[i].integrantes);    
        printf("Posicao no seu top 5: ");
        scanf("%d",&(*banda)[i].posicao);    
        getchar();
    }    
}

void mostrar (BANDAS banda)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        printf ("Nome: %s\n",banda[i].nome);
        printf ("Tipo de musica: %s\n",banda[i].tipo);
        printf ("Numero de integrantes: %d \n",banda[i].integrantes);
        printf ("Posicao no seu TOP 5: %d \n",banda[i].posicao);
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no IDEONE](http://ideone.com/y82uiF)

---

Apesar do programa funcionar desta forma, você pode deixá-lo mais legível, alterando a declararação da *struct* para armazenar apenas os dados de uma banda, e criar o *array* dentro da função *main()*.

Outras duas dicas:

1. Só utilize o *typedef* onde ele for realmente necessário, o que não é o caso para esse tipo de programas (simples).
2. O comando `__fpurge` não faz parte do padrão da linguagem `C` e deve ser evitado.

Comment: Alem dos erros apontados por voce, eu esqueci do *banda na leitura. Se o __fpurge deve ser evitado, como devo limpar o buffer? Devo usar o fgets e usar o strcspn para eliminar o "\n" ? Obrigado pela grande ajuda.

Comment: @gabriel O `gets` deve ser evitado, pois como não controla o tamanho da entrada, há um risco grande de ocorrer um *stack overflow*. O melhor, como você disse, é utilizar o `fgets`. Para limpar o buffer de entrada, você pode utilizar um *looping* do tipo: `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` (**c** é uma variável do tipo `char`)