# Como eu defino um elemento de uma Struct em C?

Tags: c, struct

Eu pretendo fazer um programa que use `structs` para armazenar dados, porém que nele já haja alguns dados inseridos, vou dar um exemplo similar:

```
struct registro
{
    char nome[30], telefone[11];
    int idade
}dados;
```

No caso eu precisaria fazer algo do tipo:

```
dados[2].nome="José";
```

Para que o programa tenha uma base nele, podendo inserir novos dados ou procurar nos já existentes, porém eu não achei nada na internet que explique como fazer isso e eu também não consegui achar nenhuma solução. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fopen+%5Bc%5D+struct

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/302677/132

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243094/132

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Vetor de struct em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173464/vetor-de-struct-em-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema, no caso eu utilizei um comando da biblioteca

```
strcpy(dados[1].nome, "José");
```